# What is Difference between creating file with File Class & FileOutputStream?

Tags: java

Hello every I have a query for creating `FILE` using **FILE CLASS & FILEOUTPUTSTREAM CLASS** . I know using **FILE CLASS** we have to use method name `createfile` to create an specific file and when we are using **FILEOUTPUTSTREAM  CLASS** then we pass string path or name with in the class initialization then that file created automatic. But Then What is Different between both the cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `File` is an abstract path. It has no physical existence.

It is only when "using" that `File` that the underlying physical storage is actually hit.

A `FileOutputStream` will handle file existence test/creation/opening etc for you.

Note: if you use Java 7, ditch `File` and use `Path` instead.

Comment: means FILE with FILE CLASS is for the those object which is not physical exists and FILEOUTPUTSTREAM is for those objects which is already exists.

Comment: No; as I said, a `FileOutputStream` will handle file creation for you (well, it depends on the constructor you use). When you create a `File` object, you create an abstract path; the underlying physical object may, or may not exist; you can only determine that when using it.

Comment: Ok so that is the difference between both of them now its clear to me +1 @fge :)

Comment: `try(BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("filename"), StandardCharSets.UTF_8)) { ... }` ftw

Answer (score 0):

The `File` class is just a handle for the file. The `FileOutputStream` is an `OutputStream` that you can write to: [FileOutputStream JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String%29).

You can think of them as `touch myfile.txt` vs. `echo > myfile.txt`

Comment: Uhm, no, `touch` will actually create the file

Comment: Yes, but we're comparing `File.createNewFile()` to creating a file via a `FileOutputStream`